# Cloud generator addon unable to create mesh?

Tags: mesh, particles

I am new to blender and I'm working on an animation centered around a plane flying through the clouds.

I am using the cloud addon particle system to generate clouds using the following tutorial as a guide. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK2l6Yrtqhg

I've got my clouds set up the way I want them but I can't convert the particles into a mesh in order to use them in other scenes. I have been told that there should be a great big convert to mesh button in the modifiers tab but it does not appear.

[image]

Have I missed something? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I took the liberty of moving your included screenshot. to Stack Exchange's imgur storage, which is the preferred image storage. To use it in the the future, hover your mouse over the icons in the text box where you type your question or answe, and you'll see that one of them is to upload images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Convert* button will only appear if you use the particle system to create duplicates of other objects or when creating hair. To create duplicate objects, under *Render* in the particle settings, change from *Halo* to either *Object* or *Group* (the latter can be used to duplicate several objects with a single particle system). In the image below, I've created 1000 duplicates of an icosphere.

[image]

To generate hair, change *Type* from *Emitter* to *Hair* in the particle settings. Since hair is probably not what you need here, I'm only mentioning it for completeness, and further explanation of it is a topic for a different question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The convert button is now available for use. However, I still can't get thing to save as a mesh. I'm unsure if it is an issue with the cloud addon or I am just doing something incorrectly.